# How to serve PDF files on the web?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I have the following code, which seems to serve a PDF without any content:

```
from pathlib import Path

pdf = Path("url/to/file.pdf")
print(f"Content-Type: application/pdf;\r\n")
print(pdf.read_bytes())
```

Any tips to correctly serve this PDF would be helpful!

Edit: for context, I am trying to serve PDF files and obscure original PDF file path on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer to my own question if anyone else needs to know:

```
pdf = Path("url/to/file.pdf")
print("Content-type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n")
stdout.flush()
stdout.buffer.write(pdf.read_bytes())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Python developer so I can't help you too specifically, but a couple things...

If your Phython script is outputting headers and content in the same response (such as via CGI), you need to have a blank line between the headers and content.  Right now you have one `\r\n`.  Add a second `\r\n`.

The other thing is that you should find a way to stream the output from that file rather than reading all its bytes and printing them.

Finally, I don't know if `print()` in Python is interpreting that as a string, but that can be problematic for binary data.  This again is solved by piping a stream directly to the output.

Answer (score -1):

I realy dont know what your question is about. Its looks like code is unrelated with question. Its seems like its suppose to find pdf in local file system(build_in open?) and then print its content(?). Do you use some framework(flask/django)?

If by dynamic serving you have in mind dynamic creation of pdf based on some template:

1. pdf may be constructed from some markdown language like html, tex file(latex unfortunately is complicated system and dont fit to be depoloyed with web app)
2. markdown language file may be in turn rendered by template soft (jinja2, django build_in)

https://weasyprint.org/ is library that convert html + css to pdf

Ps. add more context

Comment: I tried adding context. Basically, I am trying to serve PDF files while obscuring the actual file path of the PDF. That is, I want to save the PDF in a non-public accessible directory, but when an authorized user requests the PDF, I want to verify they're authorized and if so, serve the PDF.

Comment: This is not really an answer. To clarify the questions, use comments rathern than answers